# How to export arabic text from MySQL database to csv using toad for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have a table in MSQL database with arabic text in one of its columns but when i exported it to csv, It is getting converted to some other format say like

```
Ø§Ø­ØªÙØ§Ù
```

I want my arabic text to be exported instead. I think there is an issue with encoding. PLease help.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem before but I used to save as OpenDocument Spreadsheet and then open it by Excel. You may face some issues like slow save in excel but it is work, worth to try.

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer to this. It is very simple though.

I normally use quick export and save the table in CSV format.

Now instead of exporting it in CSV, if I exported it in excel format, the arabic text appears :). I don't know why that happened but it worked.

Please post if you know any better answer. Thank you :)